# Uploading PDFs via the SharePoint Graph API without using Binary?

Tags: api

I am able to upload to the SharePoint Graph API via client-side JavaScript when I send the data in binary.

However, I need to send PDF files via a server-side connection and when I do this the data must be in base64.

When I am sending the documents as Base64, they are uploaded but the files are not readable.

Anyone know what headers need to be passed in the JSON so that the Graph API will accept Base64?

Is there any additional formatting that needs to be done to the Base64 string that is passed for the body?